# nodejs regex kills process

Tags: node.js, regex

I am using nodejs v10.13.0 with VS Code as my IDE.

When I run my nodejs program,
It exits at this line:

```
let matches = address.match(reallyCrazyLongRegex);
```

- No errors
- no exceptions
- nothing

in the VS Code Terminal then I run

```
>> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
-1073741819
```

- Why is it crashing?
- Why are there no exceptions/errors when it crashes?
- What exit code is -1073741819 for nodejs?

Note, if I replace reallyCrazyLongRegex with reallySimpleTestingRegex it runs as normal.

Thanks,
Ryan

Edit: address is a mailing address

the regex:

```
 let reallyCrazyLongRegex = new RegExp([arrayOfEveryCityNameInTheUSA].map(function (v)
            {
                return "([ ]+|^)" + v + "([ ]+|$)";
            }).join("|"), "ig");
```

It's simple, just very long.

Edit2: I have split it into multiple regexes (every 1000 names)
and it works for the most part but will randomly crash with 
**JavaScript heap out of memory**
which doesn't make any sense at all cause i'm running --max-old-space-size=4048 and my node process never goes above 500MB

> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [5048:0000000000379B20]    92031 ms: Mark-sweep 293.3 (307.6) -> 293.3
>   (299.8) MB, 271.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.910, current mu = 0.000)
>   last resort GC in old space requested [5048:0000000000379B20]    92227
>   ms: Mark-sweep 293.3 (299.8) -> 293.3 (299.8) MB, 195.9 / 0.0 ms 
>   (average mu = 0.850, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space
>   requested
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> ```
> 0: ExitFrame [pc: 00000001402BAE3D]
> 1: StubFrame [pc: 00000001402FB91E] Security context: 0x01abc1840921 <JSObject>
> 2: match [000001ABC184D011](this=0x00df6da620c1 <String[30]: room no nanjing shanghai china>,0x0352098253f1 <JSRegExp <Very long string[25794]>>)
> 3: findArea [000001CEE0D6B1E1] [c:\script.js:900]
> ```
>
> [bytecode=0000035209839239 offset=430](this=0x00fab1aeb5d1
>
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory  1: 000000013F6AC80F napi_wrap+125199  2:
>   000000013F64BFE6 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+36198  3: 000000013F64CCB6
>   v8::base::CPU::has_sse+39478  4: 000000013FE744AE
>   v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94  5:
>   000000013FE5BC01 v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+785  6:
>   000000013FD22F5C
>   v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1436  7:
>   000000013FD1ED69 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1561
>   8: 000000013FD39FEC
>   v8::internal::Factory::CodeBuilder::BuildInternal+412  9:
>   000000013FD39E26 v8::internal::Factory::CodeBuilder::Build+22 10:
>   000000013F89D6E4 v8::internal::RegExpMacroAssemblerX64::GetCode+4116
>   11: 000000013FAD5101
>   v8::internal::IrregexpInterpreter::MatchInternal+7057 12:
>   000000013FAC6C80 v8::internal::RegExpParser::operator=+4544 13:
>   000000013FAC7149 v8::internal::RegExp::CompileForTesting+425 14:
>   000000013FAC74E5 v8::internal::RegExp::DotPrintForTesting+245 15:
>   000000013FAC7D68 v8::internal::RegExp::Exec+1256 16: 000000013FAC78F7
>   v8::internal::RegExp::Exec+119 17: 000000013FA74B26
>   v8::internal::DeclarationScope::was_lazily_parsed+21974 18:
>   00000001402BAE3D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+517453
>   19: 00000001402FB91E
>   v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+782382 20:
>   00000001402A6E7E v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+435598
>   21: 000000014024675B
>   v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40555 22:
>   000000014024675B v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40555
>   23: 000000014024675B
>   v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40555 24:
>   0000000140272F70 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+222848
>   25: 0000000140297C52
>   v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+373602 26:
>   0000000140265354 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+166500
>   27: 00000001402441AC
>   v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+30908 28:
>   000000013FD7ED0F v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm+1551 29:
>   000000013FD7EE03 v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm+1795 30:
>   000000013FD7F1E5 v8::internal::Execution::TryCall+357 31:
>   000000013FD61745 v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::RunMicrotasks+501 32:
>   000000013FE26BE0 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+326608 33:
>   000000013FE26120 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+323856 34:
>   000000013FE26468 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+324696 35:
>   000000013FE2626E v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+324190 36:
>   00000001402BAF1D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+517677
>   37: 000000014024675B
>   v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40555 38:
>   00000001402442BE v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+31182
>   39: 0000000140243EAC
>   v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+30140 40:
>   000000013FD7EC82 v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm+1410 41:
>   000000013FD7E5F9 v8::internal::Execution::Call+185 42:
>   000000013FE520E0 v8::Function::Call+608 43: 000000013F6C8E52
>   node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope+770 44: 000000013F6C9114
>   node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope+1476 45: 000000013F6C2093
>   v8::internal::compiler::Operator::EffectOutputCount+179 46:
>   000000013F5BFE33 v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::microtasks_policy+19395
>   47: 000000013F5C062C
>   v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::microtasks_policy+21436 48:
>   000000013F5BB6B5 v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::microtasks_policy+1093
>   49: 000000013F6E0A2B uv_tty_set_vterm_state+8299 50: 000000013F6F588C
>   uv_loop_init+844 51: 000000013F6F5BC4 uv_run+244 52: 000000013F6173F3
>   EVP_CIPHER_CTX_buf_noconst+29635 53: 000000013F6740D0 node::Start+288
>   54: 000000013F52673C RC4_options+339516 55: 0000000140377788
>   v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+1289880 56:
>   00000000775A556D BaseThreadInitThunk+13 57: 000000007790385D
>   RtlUserThreadStart+29

Comment: Did you try running your regex in node console? What happens when you do the same in console rather than application.

Comment: What's the regex?

Comment: You're hitting V8 (node.js's JavaScript engine)'s limitation. Regex wasn't meant to do what you're trying to do. Tell us what's the purpose of what you're doing, there's likely a better solution.

Comment: When you run with ` --max-old-space-size=4048` do you do this from code or from terminal manually?

Answer (score 5):

Figuring out the error code by using bash:

```
$ printf "%x" -1073741819
ffffffffc0000005
```

Ignoring the `f`'s, this is c0000005 -- an access violation.

Your regex is too complicated; node can't cope; it's crashing.

Comment: They are trying to validate the address contains a valid city name.

Comment: That was added in a later edit. Will remove my suspicion.

Answer (score 2):

There are many capture groups that should be factored out.

Unless there exist's a source of US Cities that is updated daily,
the way to do this is with
a full blown ***regex trie*** that is created offline every month or so.

**Source #1 :**  [US Cities](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/US_Cities/)
Here can be obtained a 28900 item list of the full regex.
Or individual regex as broken down by state.

This is derived from the public list obtained from https://simplemaps.com/data/us-cities.

What is interessting here is that the 52 individual regex are small and
can be compiled into a list of regex's.

A code segment can be such that inside a loop each regex is tried
until one (or multiple) by state is found.
Or, if the State is already known, the city can be checked.

---

**Source #2 :**
There are about 1950 Cities that the Encylopedia Britanica's list on their website.
This is sparce, and are the biggest populated cities.

```
(\s|^)(A(?:b(?:beville|erdeen|i(?:lene|ng(?:d|t)on))|coma|d(?:a(?:ms)?|rian)|iken|jo|kron|l(?:am(?:eda|o(?:gordo|sa))|b(?:any|ert[\t ]+Lea|uquerque)|coa|exand(?:er[\t ]+City|ria)|hambra|iquippa|l(?:entown|iance)|ma|pine|t(?:a|o(?:n|ona)|us)|va)|m(?:a(?:na[\t ]+Colonies|rillo)|bridge|e(?:ric(?:an[\t ]+Fork|us)|s(?:bury)?)|herst|sterdam)|n(?:a(?:co(?:nda|rtes)|darko|heim)|chorage|d(?:alusia|erson(?:ville)?|over)|n(?:[\t ]+Arbor|apolis|iston)|sonia|tioch)|p(?:alachicola|pleton)|r(?:cadia|dmore|ka(?:delphia|nsas[\t ]+(?:City|Post))|lington(?:[\t ]+Heights)?|t(?:esia|hur))|s(?:bury[\t ]+Park|h(?:e(?:boro|ville)|land|tabula)|pen|toria)|t(?:chison|h(?:ens|ol)|lant(?:a|ic[\t ]+City)|more|tleboro)|u(?:burn|gusta|rora|stin)|vondale)|B(?:a(?:bylon|inbridge|ker(?:[\t ]+City|sfield)|ltimore|ngor|r(?:[\t ]+Harbor|aboo|b(?:erton|ourville)|dstown|nstable|r(?:e|ington)|stow|t(?:lesville|ow))|strop|t(?:avia|esville|h|on[\t ]+Rouge|tle[\t ]+Creek)|y(?:[\t ]+(?:City|Saint[\t ]+Louis)|onne|town))|e(?:a(?:con|trice|u(?:for|mon)t|verton)|ckley|dford|l(?:en|fast|l(?:e(?:[\t ]+(?:Fourch|Glad)e|fontaine|v(?:ill|u)e)|ingham|ows[\t ]+Falls)|mont|oit|videre)|midji|n(?:d|nington|ton(?:[\t ]+Harbor)?)|r(?:ea|keley|lin)|ssemer|th(?:any|esda-Chevy[\t ]+Chase|lehem)|verly(?:[\t ]+Hills)?)|i(?:ddeford|g[\t ]+Spring|l(?:lings|oxi)|nghamton|rmingham|s(?:bee|marck))|l(?:a(?:ckfoot|irsville)|oom(?:field(?:[\t ]+Hills)?|ington|sburg)|uefield|ytheville)|o(?:ca[\t ]+Raton|galusa|ise|nners[\t ]+Ferry|o(?:n(?:e(?:sborough)?|ville)|thbay[\t ]+Harbor)|r(?:dentown|ger)|s(?:sier[\t ]+City|ton)|u(?:lder(?:[\t ]+City)?|n(?:d[\t ]+Brook|tiful)|rne)|w(?:ie|ling[\t ]+Green)|ys[\t ]+Town|zeman)|r(?:a(?:d(?:enton|ford)|in(?:erd|tree)|n(?:ford|son)|ttleboro)|e(?:a|ckenridge|merton)|i(?:dge(?:port|ton)|gh(?:am[\t ]+City|ton)|stol)|o(?:ckton|nx|ok(?:field|ings|l(?:ine|yn))|wnsville)|unswick|yan)|u(?:ckhannon|ena[\t ]+Park|ffalo|r(?:bank|lington|ns)|tte))|C(?:a(?:dillac|hokia|iro|l(?:ais|dwell|exico|houn|istoga|umet[\t ]+City)|m(?:bridge|den|pbellsville)|n(?:on[\t ]+City|ton|yon)|pe[\t ]+(?:Coral|Girardeau|May)|r(?:bondale|ibou|l(?:i(?:nvil|s)le|sbad)|mel|rollton|son[\t ]+City|thage)|s(?:a[\t ]+Grande|per|tine)|tonsville)|e(?:dar[\t ]+(?:City|Falls|Rapids)|ntral(?:[\t ]+(?:City|Falls)|ia))|h(?:a(?:dron|m(?:bersburg|paign)|n(?:dler|ute)|pel[\t ]+Hill|rl(?:e(?:s(?:[\t ]+(?:City|Town)|to(?:w)?n)|voix)|otte(?:sville)?)|ttanooga|utauqua)|e(?:boygan|ektowaga|l(?:msford|sea)|rokee|s(?:apeake|ter)|yenne)|i(?:c(?:ago(?:[\t ]+Heights)?|kas(?:aw|ha)|o(?:pee)?)|llicothe)|ula[\t ]+Vista)|i(?:cero|ncinnati)|l(?:a(?:nton|r(?:emo(?:nt|re)|ks(?:burg|dale|ville))|yton)|e(?:ar(?:field|water)|burne|veland(?:[\t ]+Heights)?)|i(?:fton|max|nton)|ovis)|o(?:coa(?:[\t ]+Beach|-Rockledge)|dy|eur[\t ]+d’Alene|ffeyville|h(?:asset|oes)|l(?:l(?:ege[\t ]+(?:Park|Station)|insville)|orado[\t ]+Springs|umb(?:ia|us))|mpton|n(?:cord|ey[\t ]+Island|ne(?:aut|rsville)|way)|o(?:keville|perstown|s[\t ]+Bay)|r(?:al[\t ]+Gables|dova|inth|ning|ona(?:do)?|pus[\t ]+Christi|t(?:ez|land)|vallis|ydon)|sta[\t ]+Mesa|u(?:lee[\t ]+Dam|ncil[\t ]+(?:Bluffs|Grove)|peville)|v(?:entry|ington))|r(?:a(?:n(?:ford|ston)|wfordsville)|ipple[\t ]+Creek|o(?:okston|ssett|wn[\t ]+Point)|ystal[\t ]+City)|u(?:l(?:lman|ver[\t ]+City)|mberland|s(?:hing|ter)|yahoga[\t ]+Falls))|D(?:a(?:hlonega|l(?:las|ton|y[\t ]+City)|n(?:bury|v(?:ers|ille))|r(?:ien|lington|tmouth)|v(?:enport|is)|yton(?:a[\t ]+Beach)?)|e(?:[\t ]+(?:Land|Smet)|Kalb|a(?:dwood|rborn)|catur|dham|erfield[\t ]+Beach|fiance|l(?:[\t ]+Rio|aware|ray[\t ]+Beach|ta)|m(?:ing|opolis)|n(?:ison|nis|ton|ver)|r(?:b|r)y|s[\t ]+(?:Mo|Pla)ines|troit|vils[\t ]+Lake)|i(?:ckins|ll|x)on|o(?:dge[\t ]+City|than|uglas|ver|wney)|u(?:buque|luth|n(?:can|kirk)|r(?:an(?:go|t)|ham)|xbury))|E(?:a(?:gle[\t ]+Pass|st(?:[\t ]+(?:Aurora|C(?:hicago|leveland)|Greenwich|Ha(?:mpton|rtford|ven)|L(?:ansing|iverpool)|Moline|Orange|P(?:oint|rovidence)|Saint[\t ]+Louis)|chester|ham|on|po(?:inte|rt))|u[\t ]+Claire)|corse|d(?:enton|gartown|i(?:nburg|son)|mond)|ffingham|l(?:[\t ]+(?:Ce(?:ntr|rrit)o|Dorado|Monte|Paso|Reno)|gin|izabeth(?:[\t ]+City|to(?:w)?n)?|k(?:[\t ]+City|hart|ins|o|ton)|l(?:ensburg|sworth)|m(?:hurst|ira)|wood|y(?:ria)?)|m(?:mitsburg|poria)|n(?:field|glewood|id|terprise)|phrata|rie|s(?:c(?:anaba|ondido)|sex|t(?:es[\t ]+Park|herville))|u(?:clid|faula|gene|reka)|v(?:ans(?:ton|ville)|e(?:leth|rett))|x(?:celsior[\t ]+Springs|eter))|F(?:a(?:ir(?:banks|f(?:ax|ield)|haven|mont)|l(?:l(?:[\t ]+River|on|s[\t ]+Church)|mouth)|r(?:go|ibault|mington)|yetteville)|er(?:gus(?:[\t ]+Falls|on)|nandina[\t ]+Beach)|i(?:llmore|ndlay|t(?:chburg|zgerald))|l(?:agstaff|int|or(?:ence|issant)|ushing)|o(?:n(?:d[\t ]+du[\t ]+Lac|tana)|r(?:est[\t ]+Hills|rest[\t ]+City|t[\t ]+(?:Benton|Collins|Dodge|Kent|L(?:auderdal|e)e|M(?:organ|yers)|P(?:ayn|ierc)e|S(?:cott|mith)|Valley|W(?:a(?:lton[\t ]+Beach|yne)|orth))))|r(?:a(?:mingham|nk(?:fort|lin))|e(?:d(?:erick(?:sburg)?|onia)|eport|mont|nch[\t ]+Lick|sno))|ul(?:ler)?ton)|G(?:a(?:dsden|ffney|inesville|l(?:e(?:na|sburg)|l(?:atin|ipolis|up)|veston)|r(?:d(?:en[\t ]+(?:City|Grove)|iner)|land|y)|stonia|tlinburg)|e(?:n(?:ev|o)a|orgetown|rmantown|ttysburg)|il(?:a[\t ]+Bend|lette)|l(?:assboro|en(?:[\t ]+Ellyn|d(?:al|iv)e|s[\t ]+Falls|view|wood[\t ]+Springs)|o(?:be|ucester|versville))|o(?:l(?:d(?:en|field|sboro)|iad)|shen)|r(?:a(?:fton|n(?:d[\t ]+(?:Forks|Haven|Island|Junction|Rapids)|ite[\t ]+City|ts(?:[\t ]+Pass)?)|yling)|e(?:at[\t ]+(?:B(?:arrington|end)|Falls|Neck)|e(?:ley|n(?:[\t ]+(?:Bay|River)|belt|eville|field|sb(?:oro|urg)|ville|w(?:ich|ood)))|nada|tna)|innell|o(?:sse[\t ]+Pointe|ton))|u(?:ilford|lfport|n(?:nison|tersville)|thrie|ymon))|H(?:a(?:ckensack|ddonfield|gerstown|ines|l(?:ifax|landale[\t ]+Beach)|m(?:den|ilton|mond(?:sport)?|pton)|n(?:alei|cock|nibal|over)|r(?:l(?:an|em|ingen)|mony|pers[\t ]+Ferry|r(?:is(?:burg|on)|odsburg)|t(?:ford|sville)|wich)|stings|ttiesburg|v(?:erhill|re)|y(?:s|ward)|z(?:ard|leton))|e(?:ber[\t ]+City|lena|mpstead|nderson|r(?:kimer|rin|shey))|i(?:aleah|bbing|ckory|gh(?:[\t ]+Point|land[\t ]+Park)|l(?:lsboro(?:ugh)?|o)|n(?:gham|ton))|o(?:b(?:art|bs|oken)|dgenville|l(?:denville|l(?:and|y(?:[\t ]+Springs|wood))|yoke)|me(?:r|stead)|n(?:aunau|esdale|olulu)|od[\t ]+River|p(?:e(?:well)?|kinsville)|quiam|t[\t ]+Springs|u(?:ghton|lton|ma|ston))|u(?:dson|go|nt(?:ington(?:[\t ]+Beach)?|sville)|ron|tchinson)|y(?:a(?:nnis|ttsville)|de[\t ]+Park))|I(?:daho[\t ]+(?:City|Falls)|lion|n(?:d(?:ependence|i(?:an(?:a(?:polis)?|ola)|o))|glewood|ter(?:lochen|national[\t ]+Falls))|owa[\t ]+City|pswich|r(?:on(?:[\t ]+Mountain|wood)|vin(?:e|g(?:ton)?))|shpeming|thaca)|J(?:a(?:ckson(?:ville)?|mestown|nesville|sper)|e(?:annette|fferson(?:[\t ]+City|ville)|rsey[\t ]+City)|im[\t ]+Thorpe|o(?:hn(?:[\t ]+Day|s(?:on[\t ]+City|town))|liet|nesboro(?:ugh)?|plin)|un(?:ction[\t ]+City|eau))|K(?:a(?:hului|l(?:amazoo|ispell)|n(?:ab|eohe|kakee|sas[\t ]+City)|paa|skaskia|waihae)|e(?:arney|ene|l(?:logg|so)|n(?:ne(?:bunkport|wick)|osha|t)|okuk|t(?:chikan|tering)|wanee|y(?:[\t ]+West|ser))|i(?:l(?:gore|leen)|n(?:g(?:man|s(?:port|ton|ville))|ston)|rksville|tt(?:ery|y[\t ]+Hawk))|lamath[\t ]+Falls|noxville|o(?:diak|komo|tzebue))|L(?:a(?:[\t ]+(?:Crosse|Gran(?:d|g)e|Habra|Junta|Salle)|c(?:kawann|oni)a|fayette|guna[\t ]+Beach|haina|ie|ke(?:[\t ]+(?:C(?:harles|ity)|Forest|Geneva|Havasu[\t ]+City|Oswego|Placid|Wales)|hurst|land|view|wood)|mar|n(?:caster|der|sing)|r(?:amie|edo|go)|s[\t ]+(?:Cruce|Vega)s|urel|w(?:rence|ton)|yton)|e(?:a(?:d(?:ville)?|venworth)|banon|hi|nox|ominster|vittown|w(?:es|is(?:burg|to(?:w)?n))|xington)|i(?:ber(?:al|tyville)|ma|ncoln|sle|t(?:chfield|tle(?:[\t ]+(?:Falls|Rock)|ton))|v(?:ermore|ingston|onia))|o(?:ck(?:[\t ]+Haven|port)|di|gan|m(?:bard|poc)|ng(?:[\t ]+B(?:ea|ran)ch|mont|view)|rain|s[\t ]+A(?:lamo|ngele)s|uisville|v(?:eland|ington)|we(?:ll|r[\t ]+Southampton))|u(?:b(?:bock|ec)|d(?:ington|low)|fkin|mberton)|yn(?:chburg|n))|M(?:a(?:c(?:hias|kinaw[\t ]+City|o(?:mb|n))|dison|gnolia|l(?:den|ibu)|maroneck|n(?:assas|chester|dan|hattan|i(?:stee|towoc)|kato|sfield|ti)|r(?:blehead|i(?:etta|nette|on)|lborough|quette|shall|tin(?:ez|s(?:[\t ]+Ferry|burg|ville))|y(?:s)?ville)|s(?:on[\t ]+City|s(?:ena|illon))|ttoon|y(?:field|sville))|c(?:Al(?:ester|len)|Cook|K(?:eesport|inney)|Minnville|Pherson)|e(?:adville|d(?:ford|icine[\t ]+Lodge)|lbourne|mphis|n(?:asha|lo[\t ]+Park|ominee|tor)|r(?:ced|id(?:e|ia)n)|s(?:a|quite)|xico)|i(?:ami(?:[\t ]+Beach)?|chigan[\t ]+City|d(?:dle(?:bury|sboro|town)|land|west[\t ]+City)|l(?:an|bank|es[\t ]+City|ford|l(?:burn|edgeville|ville)|ton|waukee)|n(?:den|eola|neapolis|ot)|s(?:hawaka|s(?:ion|oula))|tchell)|o(?:ab|b(?:il|ridg)e|desto|line|n(?:ett|mouth|roe(?:ville)?|t(?:clair|erey|gomery|icello|pelier|rose))|or(?:e|head)|r(?:ehead[\t ]+City|gan(?:[\t ]+City|to(?:w)?n)|ri(?:lto|stow)n)|s(?:cow|es[\t ]+Lake)|un(?:dsville|t(?:[\t ]+(?:Clemens|Holly|Pleasant|Vernon)|ain[\t ]+View)))|u(?:n(?:cie|delein)|r(?:freesboro|ray)|s(?:catine|k(?:egon|ogee)))|y(?:rtle[\t ]+Beach|stic))|N(?:a(?:cogdoches|gs[\t ]+Head|hant|mpa|nticoke|p(?:a|erville|les|panee)|rragansett|sh(?:ua|ville)|t(?:ch(?:ez|itoches)|ick)|u(?:gatuck|voo))|e(?:braska[\t ]+City|e(?:dles|nah)|osho|phi|w(?:[\t ]+(?:Albany|B(?:e(?:dford|rn)|r(?:aunfels|itain|unswick))|Castle|Glarus|H(?:a(?:rmony|ven)|ope)|Iberia|Kensington|London|M(?:a(?:drid|r(?:ket|tinsville))|ilford)|Orleans|P(?:altz|hiladelphia)|Rochelle|Smyrna[\t ]+Beach|Ulm|Windsor|York[\t ]+City)|ark|b(?:erg|ur(?:gh|yport))|castle|port(?:[\t ]+(?:Beach|News))?|ton))|i(?:agara[\t ]+Fall|le)s|o(?:gales|me|r(?:folk|ma[ln]|ris(?:town)?|t(?:h(?:[\t ]+(?:Adams|C(?:hicago|ollege[\t ]+Hill)|H(?:aven|empstead)|Kingstown|L(?:as[\t ]+Vegas|ittle[\t ]+Rock)|Platte)|ampton|field)|on)|w(?:alk|ich|ood))|vato)|yack)|O(?:ak(?:[\t ]+(?:Harbor|Park|Ridge)|land)|berlin|c(?:ala|ean(?:[\t ]+(?:City|Springs)|side)|onto)|dessa|gden(?:sburg)?|il[\t ]+City|jai|k(?:lahoma[\t ]+City|mulgee)|l(?:athe|d[\t ]+Saybrook|ean|ympia)|maha|n(?:e(?:id|ont)a|tario)|pel(?:ika|ousas)|r(?:a(?:ibi|nge(?:burg)?)|derville|e(?:gon(?:[\t ]+City)?|m)|lando|mond[\t ]+Beach|o(?:no|ville))|s(?:awatomie|ceola|hkosh|kaloosa|sining|wego)|tt(?:a|um)wa|uray|verland[\t ]+Park|w(?:atonna|ensboro)|x(?:fo|na)rd|yster[\t ]+Bay|zark)|P(?:a(?:cific[\t ]+Grove|ducah|gosa[\t ]+Springs|inesville|l(?:at(?:ine|ka)|m(?:[\t ]+(?:B(?:ay|each)|Springs)|dale|er|yra)|o[\t ]+Alto)|mpa|n(?:ama[\t ]+City|guitch)|r(?:is|k(?:[\t ]+(?:City|Forest|Ridge)|ersburg)|ma|sippany–Troy[\t ]+Hills)|s(?:adena|c(?:agoula|o)|s(?:[\t ]+Christian|aic))|terson|uls[\t ]+Valley|w(?:huska|tucket)|yson)|e(?:abody|cos|ekskill|kin|n(?:dleton|sacola)|oria|r(?:ry|th[\t ]+Amboy|u)|shtigo|t(?:aluma|er(?:borough|sburg)|oskey))|h(?:arr|enix[\t ]+City|il(?:adelphia|ippi)|oenix(?:ville)?)|i(?:erre|ne(?:[\t ]+Bluff|hurst)|pestone|qua|tts(?:burgh?|field))|l(?:a(?:in(?:field|s|view)|no|tts(?:burg|mout)h)|ymouth)|o(?:catello|int[\t ]+(?:Pleasant|Roberts)|m(?:ona|pano[\t ]+Beach)|n(?:ca[\t ]+City|tiac)|rt(?:[\t ]+(?:A(?:ngeles|rthur)|Gibson|Hu(?:eneme|ron)|Lavaca|Orford|Washington)|a(?:ge|les)|land|smouth)|t(?:sdam|ts(?:town|ville))|ughkeepsie|well)|r(?:airie[\t ]+du[\t ]+Chien|es(?:cott|que[\t ]+Isle)|i(?:c(?:e|hard)|est[\t ]+River|n(?:ceton|eville))|ov(?:i(?:dence|ncetown)|o)|yor)|u(?:eblo|llman|t-in-Bay|yallup))|Qu(?:eens|incy)|R(?:a(?:cine|leigh|n(?:cho[\t ]+Cucamonga|dolph|toul)|pid[\t ]+City|ton|wlins)|e(?:ading|d(?:[\t ]+(?:Bluff|Cloud|Wing)|ding|lands|mond|ondo[\t ]+Beach|wood[\t ]+City)|edsport|n(?:o|sselaer|ton)|ston|vere|xburg)|hinelander|i(?:ch(?:ardson|land|mond)|dgewood|pon|ver(?:[\t ]+Forest|side|ton))|o(?:anoke|c(?:hester|k(?:[\t ]+(?:Hill|Island|Springs)|ford|land|ville|y[\t ]+Mount))|gers|lla|m(?:e|ney)|s(?:e(?:burg|lle|ville)|well)|tterdam|yal[\t ]+Oak)|u(?:gby|mford|ston|t(?:herfor|lan)d)|ye)|S(?:a(?:c(?:rament)?o|g(?:[\t ]+Harbor|inaw)|int(?:[\t ]+(?:A(?:lbans|ugustine)|C(?:harles|loud)|George|Ignace|Jo(?:hnsbury|seph)|Louis|Mar(?:tinville|ys[\t ]+City)|P(?:aul|etersburg))|e[\t ]+Genevieve)|l(?:em|i(?:nas?|sbury)|lisaw|t[\t ]+Lake[\t ]+City)|n(?:[\t ]+(?:An(?:gel|toni)o|Bernardino|Clemente|Diego|F(?:e(?:lipe|rnando)|rancisco)|Gabriel|J(?:ose|uan[\t ]+Capistrano)|L(?:eandr|uis[\t ]+Obisp)o|Ma(?:r(?:cos|ino)|teo)|Pedro|Rafael|Simeon)|d(?:[\t ]+Springs|usky|wich)|ford|ta[\t ]+(?:Ana|Barbara|C(?:la(?:r(?:it)?a|us)|ruz)|Fe|Monica|Rosa))|pulpa|ra(?:nac[\t ]+Lake|sota|toga[\t ]+Springs)|u(?:gus|k[\t ]+Centre|lt[\t ]+Sainte[\t ]+Marie|salito)|vannah)|c(?:ar(?:borough|sdale)|henectady|otts(?:boro|dale)|ranton)|e(?:a(?:rcy|side|ttle)|bring|dalia|lma|minole|neca[\t ]+Falls|ward|ymour)|h(?:a(?:ker[\t ]+Heights|mokin|ron|wnee(?:town)?)|e(?:boygan|ffield|l(?:by(?:ville)?|ton)|pherdstown|r(?:id|m)an)|iprock|reveport)|i(?:dney|erra[\t ]+Vista|lver(?:[\t ]+(?:City|Spring)|ton)|m(?:i[\t ]+Valle|sbur)y|oux[\t ]+(?:City|Falls)|tka)|k(?:agway|okie)|m(?:ith[\t ]+Center|yrna)|o(?:corro|mer(?:sworth|ville)|noma|uth(?:[\t ]+(?:Bend|Charleston|H(?:adley|olland)|Kingstown|Orange[\t ]+Village|Sa(?:int[\t ]+Paul|n[\t ]+Francisco))|ampton|ington))|p(?:a(?:nish[\t ]+Fork|r(?:ks|tanburg))|earfish|okane|ring(?:[\t ]+Green|field|ville))|t(?:a(?:mford|rkville|te(?:[\t ]+College|n[\t ]+Island)|unton)|e(?:amboat[\t ]+Springs|rling|ubenville|vens[\t ]+Point)|illwater|o(?:ck(?:bridge|ton)|n(?:ington|y[\t ]+(?:Brook|Point))|ughton)|r(?:atford|eator|oudsburg)|u(?:r(?:bridge|g(?:eon[\t ]+Bay|is))|ttgart))|u(?:dbury|ffolk|m(?:m(?:ersville|it)|ter)|n(?:[\t ]+Valley|bury|nyvale)|perior|sanville)|w(?:arthmore|eetwater)|y(?:lacauga|racuse))|T(?:a(?:coma|hlequah|koma[\t ]+Park|lla(?:dega|hassee)|m(?:aqu|p)a|os|r(?:pon[\t ]+Springs|rytown)|unton)|e(?:lluride|mp(?:l)?e|n[\t ]+Sleep|rre[\t ]+Haute|wksbury|xa(?:rkana|s[\t ]+City))|h(?:e(?:[\t ]+(?:Dalles|Village)|rmopolis)|ibodaux|ousand[\t ]+Oaks)|i(?:conderoga|ffin|llamook|tusville|verton)|o(?:ccoa|ledo|mbstone|nawanda|oele|peka|rr(?:ance|ington)|towa|wson)|r(?:averse[\t ]+City|enton|inidad|oy|u(?:ro|th[\t ]+or[\t ]+Consequences))|u(?:c(?:son|umcari)|l(?:lahom|s)a|pelo|rlock|s(?:c(?:aloos|umbi)a|kegee))|win[\t ]+Falls|yler)|U(?:kiah|nion(?:[\t ]+City|town)?|rbana|tica|valde)|V(?:a(?:il|l(?:d(?:ez|osta)|le(?:jo|y[\t ]+City)|paraiso)|n(?:[\t ]+Buren|couver|dalia))|e(?:n(?:ice|tura)|r(?:million|nal))|i(?:c(?:ksburg|tor(?:ia|ville))|n(?:cennes|eland|ita)|r(?:den|ginia(?:[\t ]+(?:Beach|City))?)|salia))|W(?:a(?:bash|co|h(?:iawa|peton)|i(?:luku|mea)|l(?:l(?:a[\t ]+Walla|ingford)|nut[\t ]+Creek|pi|senburg)|r(?:m[\t ]+Springs|ner[\t ]+Robins|ren(?:sburg)?|wick)|shington|t(?:er(?:bury|ford|loo|town|v(?:ille|liet))|kins[\t ]+Glen|ts)|u(?:ke(?:gan|sha)|sau|watosa)|y(?:cross|ne(?:sboro)?))|e(?:atherford|bster(?:[\t ]+City)?|ehawken|irton|l(?:ch|l(?:esley|fleet|sburg))|natchee|st(?:[\t ]+(?:Allis|B(?:end|ridgewater)|C(?:hester|ovina)|Des[\t ]+Moines|Ha(?:rtford|ven)|Lafayette|Memphis|New[\t ]+York|Orange|P(?:alm[\t ]+Beach|lains|oint)|S(?:eneca|pringfield))|erly|field|minster|on|port)|thersfield|woka|ymouth)|h(?:e(?:aton|eling)|it(?:e[\t ]+(?:Plains|S(?:p|ulphur[\t ]+Sp)rings)|man|tier))|i(?:c(?:hita(?:[\t ]+Falls)?|kford)|l(?:kes-Barre|l(?:i(?:ams(?:burg|on|port|town)|mantic|ngboro|ston)|mar)|m(?:ette|ington)|son)|n(?:chester|d(?:ham|ow[\t ]+Rock|sor(?:[\t ]+Locks)?)|ne(?:mucc|tk)a|o(?:na|oski)|s(?:low|t(?:ed|on-Salem))|ter[\t ]+(?:Haven|Park))|sconsin[\t ]+Dells)|o(?:burn|o(?:d(?:[\t ]+River|bridge|land|s(?:[\t ]+Hole|tock)|ward)|nsocket|ster)|r(?:cester|land|thington))|yandotte)|Xenia|Y(?:a(?:kima|nkton|zoo[\t ]+City)|ellow[\t ]+Springs|o(?:nkers|r(?:ba[\t ]+Linda|k)|ungstown)|psilanti|sleta|u(?:ba[\t ]+City|ma))|Z(?:anesville|ion))(?!\S)
```

This matches all 1960 cities in about 3 ms., and is only about 14k in size.

https://regex101.com/r/qVcHf6/1

---

These regex  are extremely fast being a ternary trie.

You can do this too, it was generated using this [Ternary Trie Tool](http://www.regexformat.com/version7_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that your complicated regex is causing "redos" to your node.js server. Since node.js is single-threaded it tries to resolve your regex expression using way too much CPU which after some time crushes node execution.

You can prevent that by not using your own regex and try to use some well known regexes or if it is for validation use something like [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) or [validator.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)

Here is something about "redos":

https://blog.malwarebytes.com/security-world/technology/2018/08/explained-regular-expression-regex/

or

https://javascript.info/regexp-catastrophic-backtracking

Hope this helps :)